# What is move(+1) and move(-1)?

Tags: java, android

I came across a line of code while doing a tutorial online and there's a particular wording that I never saw before which is move(-1) or move(+1), can someone explain me what it actually means, here's the code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageButton1:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        break;      
    case R.id.imageButton2:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AddAlarmActivity.class));
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton3:
        move(-1);
        rangeText.setText(getRangeStr());
        ((SimpleCursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).changeCursor(createCursor());
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton4:
        move(+1);
        rangeText.setText(getRangeStr());
        ((SimpleCursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).changeCursor(createCursor());
        break;}}
```

Comment: It's a method call. Can't say what it does without seeing its code (and even then, no guarantees).

Comment: Those are method calls to some method in the class.  `-1` is "negative one" and `+1` is "positive one" though it can also simply be written as `1`.

Comment: "some method in the class" not necessarily. It could be a statically-imported method from another class.

Comment: Or statically-import method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block in question is from this repo https://github.com/ayttunc/BabySitterApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/murat/benimbebegim/ActivityAlarm.java#L201

The move method accepts an `integer` and jumps in the calendar so many days setting a reminder.

```
private String move(int step) {
        switch(RemindMe.getDateRange()) {
            case 0:
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1*step);
                break;
            case 1:
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7*step);
                break;
            case 2:
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1*step);
                break;
            case 3:
                cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1*step);
                break;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a function call.

"Move" in this case being the function in question.